# How to create a variable that library code can use and a user can set?

Tags: c++, variables, scope, singleton, shared-libraries

1) I want to use variable `n_threads` inside my library code (that is distributed in shared library form on Windows and Linux) in multiple `.cpp` files.

2) I want to make library user to set it.

How to do such thing in C++?

- I tried global file with `static` variables - it leads to each `.cpp` file having its copy;
- I have tried just to keep it in a namespace which leads to variable being already defined in other translation units and thus library not compiling
- I have tried `external` (which works on Linux with `.so` and does compile on Windows MSVC14) which leads to library not compiling due to unresolved externals.

What can be done to make global variable used in multiple library `.cpp` files be setable from outside (from library user code)?

Comment: How did your second attempt fail? You were saying `namespace foo { extern int var; }` I suppose?

Comment: Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int foo::n_threads" fot the third attempt

Comment: Error LNK2005 "int foo::n_threads" already defined in bla.obj for the second

Answer (score -1):

It's possible for a shared library to export a variable even in Windows. However, better just leave the variable as an internal singleton and provide an exported function to set it.